# How do I map 'Ctrl+C' to the button on RaspberryPi?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3

I've written a script that periodically scrapes twitter data using while True.

For the except element, I initiate a one-time scrape of a large chunk of data.

The only way I can trigger this is by using Ctrl+C. What I want to do is map the 'Ctrl+C' function to the button on my RaspberryPi Pibrella.

I've looked around here, there, and everywhere, but had no joy. The only module I can find does not work on Raspberry Pi (Linux).

```
def status_update():  
    while True:  
        try:  
            scrape_some_stuff()  
            time.sleep(1x60)  
        except:  
            scrape_lots_of_stuff()  
            time.sleep(1x60)
```

Comment: You could access the gpio directly from your script and stop the loop.

Comment: Are you using the `pibrella` module? If so, look at this http://www.raspberry-pi-geek.com/Archive/2014/05/Pibrella-board-for-Raspberry-Pi. You can read the button state and then trigger your `except`

Answer (score 0):

pibrella has a package (`pip install pibrella`) so you can easily monitor the button status, with which you can use to raise your exception

```
import pibrella

# add this line into your codes
pibrella.button.pressed(raise Exception)
```

Their [github repo](https://github.com/pimoroni/pibrella) has some examples.